# Get none from this function, why?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
alder = int(input("Din alder: "))
reiserute = int(input("Hvilken reiserute: "))


def bilett_pris(alder, reiserute):

    if alder <= 2:
        return 0

        rutepristabell = {
            "rute1": 150,
            "rute2": 250,
            "rute3": 50,
        }

        rutepris = rutepristabell[reiserute]

        alder_rabatt = 0.65
        if alder <= 65:
            alder_rabatt = 0
        if alder <= 16:
            alder_rabatt = 0.5

            return rutepris - rutepris * alder_rabatt

print(bilett_pris(alder, reiserute))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check that your indentation is correct.  As is, the final ```return rutepris - rutepris * alder_rabatt``` looks like it's associated to the ```if alder <= 16:``` block

Comment: @ewokx That wasn't the only indentation issue.

Comment: @AKX right.  That last return line jumped out at me first more than others.  But yeah,  the indentation's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A function that does not reach any other `return` statement implicitly returns `None`.

Python is an indentation sensitive language. There are two indentation problems in your code.

Firstly, looking at the start of your function

```
    if alder <= 2:
        return 0

        rutepristabell = {
            ...
```

you can see that the entire function body is inside the `alder <= 2` block. Since the first statement of that block is a `return`, the rest of the function is unreachable.

Secondly, near the end,

```
       if alder <= 16:
            alder_rabatt = 0.5

            return rutepris - rutepris * alder_rabatt
```

the other `return` is also misindented to be inside the other `if`, so even if you did fix the first issue, you'd only ever reach a `return` if `alder <= 16`.

The correct indentation is

```
def bilett_pris(alder, reiserute):

    if alder <= 2:
        return 0

    rutepristabell = {
        "rute1": 150,
        "rute2": 250,
        "rute3": 50,
    }

    rutepris = rutepristabell[reiserute]

    alder_rabatt = 0.65
    if alder <= 65:
        alder_rabatt = 0
    if alder <= 16:
        alder_rabatt = 0.5

    return rutepris - rutepris * alder_rabatt
```

and as you can see, there's always a definite `return` now.

Comment: Thanks, but get this output now:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/bd751c33b6710f4f/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    print (bilett_pris (alder, reiserute))
  File "/tmp/sessions/bd751c33b6710f4f/main.py", line 15, in bilett_pris
    rutepris = rutepristabell[reiserute]
KeyError: 3

Comment: That's a different error. Your `rutepristabell` does not have a `3` key. Change `"rute3"` to `3`.